# Classic example of a non exact form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $\dfrac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}$ be a 1-form defined in $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{0\}$. 
Where can I find a detailed proof that it is not exact? I would prefer a proof that doesn't use results about conservative vector fields (I know that way). I have searched Jefree Lee, Do Carmo & some others, but they all skip this part.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "conservative results", and what kind of proof you *do* want?

Comment: @NateEldredge - I think he means in terms of conservative vector fields http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field

Comment: @Sharkos: Ok, but I think any proof is going to use those ideas, whether or not it uses those words.

Comment: I am sorry about my lack of details, I should have been more explicit. I meant that the books I have read say that a 1-form is exact if and only if it is conservative, i.e., the integral of the form is 0 for any closed path, and they show that the integral along the unit circle is $2pi$, so it cannot be exact. I would like to see any different kind of proof, and the easiest one possible.  If you all agree that the most basic one must be this one, I'll try again to read and understand fully. Thanks.

Comment: Robert - I agree with @NateEldredge. Since the form is closed, the only thing that could make it not exact is global structure, and the only way to probe structure is integration. I've added a brief discussion to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure whether this is acceptable or not, but the simplest thing to do (since the form is closed) is to attempt to integrate it to find supposed $\phi$ such that your form $\omega$ is $\mathrm d \phi$.

One can derive a contradiction most straightforwardly by going around a circle, say $x^2+y^2=1$. We use the path $x(t)=\cos t,y(t)=\sin t$.
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \omega = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos^2 t +\sin^2 t}{1}\mathrm d t = 2\pi$$

But if $\omega=\mathrm d \phi$ then the expression on the left is $\phi((1,0))-\phi((1,0))=0$, a contradiction.

---

In response to your complaints about this method: The **definition** of *exact* is that $\omega=\mathrm d \phi$ for some $\phi$. The only result we've used is that integrals of derivatives are given by boundary values (a very mini version of Stokes's theorem), i.e. 
$$\int_{\mathbf x}^{\mathbf y} \mathrm d \phi = \left[\int_{t_x}^{t_y} \frac{\mathrm d \phi}{\mathrm d t} \mathrm d t = \right]\phi({\mathbf y})-\phi({\mathbf x})$$
which I don't think is really a mysterious result. If there's something you're not happy with do just say.

Comment: Much thakns, I'll read again carefully this weekend because I do not have time now, and I'm tired. But  I think it's enough. Thanks again.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Did you downvote this too? Seems somewhat extreme given I explained the logic rather than used it arbitrarily and received kind words from the OP in response. Ah well...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, everyone's doing the standard FTC proof we all know. Instead, let's try to integrate to find a potential function $f$. In the right half-plane you get $f(x,y) = \arctan(y/x)$. Now, to get a continuous continuation of this into the upper left half-plane, we need to use
$g(x,y) = \arctan(x/y)+\pi/2$. To continue this into the lower left half-plane, we need
$h(x,y) = \arctan(y/x)+\pi$, and, finally, into the lower right half-plane, we need $k(x,y)=\arctan(x,y)+3\pi/2$. So, piecing, these together, we have a continuous potential function defined on $\mathbb R^2 - \{(x,0): x>0\}$. But $f(1,0) = 0$ and $\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)} k(x,y) = 2\pi$, so there's no continuous potential function on $\mathbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}$.

Of course, this $2\pi$ is the same thing we got by integrating the closed $1$-form around the circle. It represents the fact that the polar angle has made one full revolution.

Now, how do I know my construction is essentially unique and that there is no cleverer way around it?  Potential functions on a connected set are unique up to constants. So, up to shifting by a constant, my attempt is the only possible function.

Comment: Very nice Ted. Master in Teaching. +1

Comment: I really don't see how this is any different to integrating around a circle, except that one has to carefully keep track of several limits at all the boundaries.

Comment: @Sharkos, I commented on this in my discussion. However, pedagogically, trying to construct a potential function and seeing the effort fail explicitly is different from a proof by contrapositive that one cannot exist.  A fancy remark is that cohomology as an obstruction to global patching is the motivation/definition of Čech cohomology or sheaf cohomology.

Comment: Perhaps this is a subjective feeling, so let's leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

If you integrate it along a circle containing the origin in its interior, you get a nonzero value (try it! put $x=\cos \theta, y = \sin \theta$). If the form were exact, the integral would vanish.

I don't know if that's what you mean by a "conservative result", but this is really **the** reason why this form isn't exact.

Comment: Much thanks also for you.

Comment: This is, imo, the shortest, most direct and simplest way to show what the OP wanted. +1

Comment: The sentence "If the form were exact, the integral would vanish" is precisely what the OP was forbidding.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Ah, I suspected it, hence the disclaimer. Did I deserve the downvote for this reason?

Comment: My apologies, @Bruno, I've gotten downvotes for far less than that! I owe you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this using the Green's function for the vector derivative.

There exists a Green's function $G$ for the vector derivative $\partial$:

$$\partial \cdot G = \delta \implies G(r) = \frac{r}{2\pi |r|^2}$$

The Hodge dual of this field is what you're looking for.

$$\partial \cdot G = \delta \implies \partial \wedge (Gi) = i \delta$$

All we have to do then is compute the Hodge dual $Gi$:

$$\omega = Gi = \frac{ri}{2\pi |r|^2} = \frac{x \sigma^y - y \sigma^x}{2 \pi |r|^2}$$

where $\sigma^x, \sigma^y$ are basis covectors.  Thus, $\partial \wedge \omega = i\delta$, the (dual of the) Dirac delta function, and $\omega$ is therefore not exact.

Comment: This is really hard to decipher for those of us who aren't used to your notation on a daily basis. Your $\partial$ is my $d$, and you're using $i$ where I would use $\star$, I guess. But I will comment that saying $d\omega = 2\pi \delta dx\wedge dy$ (where $\omega$ is the OP's $1$-form) is, via Green's Theorem (or Stokes's Theorem), equivalent to integrating around the circle :)

Comment: Yes, $\partial \wedge \omega = d\omega$, but $\partial \cdot G$ is an interior derivative. The notation is consistent with geometric calculus texts. And yes, once you integrate and use Stokes' theorem, you get the same result. But hey, you don't *need* to do any integration to do this, as long as you're comfortable with delta functions.

Comment: The exponential function exp(ix) maps the real line onto the unit circle and the image under its differential of the constant unit length vector field is the unit tangent firld to the circle.

Comment: sorry scratch the above ...I guess this is still the same. The differential form is just dtheta on the unit circle. But the function theta can not be defined and continuous on the whole circle